# manually calling click() on a button, can I pass any parameters?

Tags: jquery

I am manually calling .click() on a button on a page in my jquery/javascript code.

I need to pass a parameter to click that I can then read on the function that responds to the click event.

is this possible?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to invoke `.trigger()`. You can pass over any amount of arguments there.

```
$('element').trigger('click', [arg1, arg2, ...]);
```

These extra parameters are then passed into the event handler:

```
$('element').bind('click', function(event, arg1, arg2, ...) {
});
```

Reference: [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Comment: What if event handler already has parameters? Like, I have a button in a grid: <button onclick='myfunc(1,2,3)'>test</button> - what happens with params if I trigger click event on that button?

Answer (score 2):

```
<button id='test'>

var btn = $("button#test");
btn.attr("param", "my parameter");
btn.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

No. Your `onclick` event is separate from your `click()` function. Normally, this would be possible through `arguments[]`, but in this case you're going to have to use a variable.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of argument do you want to pass? I get that these argument are static, since clicking on a button cannot give you any sort of computation.

When you catch the click, you can use `this`, thus, use it to see what kind of arguments you want to pass

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="foo" />
```

And your JS:

```
<script>

function iNeedParams(bar, baz) {
  // Computation
}

$("id").click(function() {
  var me = $(this);
  // me contains the object
  // me.attr("id") gives you its ID, then you can call
  iNeedParams("hello", "world");
});
</script>
```