# trigger click event and add params to it - angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Similar to what this user is trying to acheive:
[manually calling click() on a button, can I pass any parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776013/manually-calling-click-on-a-button-can-i-pass-any-parameters)

I would like to do the same in angular JS.
Something like:
`angular.element("mySelector").trigger("click",[{param1:val1}]);`

and the access `param1` in the triggered function:
`scope.toggleForm = function ($event) {alert($event.param1);}`

Please note that angular.element("mySelector") returns an array of elements which i want to trigger the click event for each one of them separately.

Do you think this is possible?
I guess I'm going to use $broadcast eventually but would love to hear some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, welcome to the wonderful world of [Closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) :)

You can do it like this:

Note: I wrote this example in the controller just for brevity. All DOM manipulation should be done inside directives!

```
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
    angular.forEach(elems, function (elem) {
        angular.element(elem).bind('click', (function (x) {
            return function () {
                console.log(x); //prints woohoo
                alert(this.innerHTML);
            }
        })('woohoo'));
    });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/19165/)

Comment: I think you didn't understood my question. I wanted to ask how can i trigger a "click" event and pass the invoked function some data.
With jQuery its pretty simple but i wanted to do it with angular.
I eventually ended up using $broadcast and $on to handle my needs since it was the "angular" way of doing so in that case.

Any way the article about Closures was AWESOME!!! so thanks for that!

Comment: 1) I'm glad it helped. 2) I thought you wanted a way to pass parameters in the click? The 'woohoo' I wrote was an example of parameter passing, it could be anything you want. Then you have it as 'x' in the function. 3) I advise against using `$on`/`$broadcast` in the application as it pollutes the scopes. It is usually recommended to avoid using it.